# Even? function in Scheme (Dr. Racket)

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to write a program in Scheme to compute the result of the power function using the fast power algorithm/recursion. The algorithm should be correct, but somewhere my syntax is off. The program compiles, but when I input a base and exp to test, Dr. Racket freezes up and runs out of memory. Having a difficult time locating online examples for how the (even?) function should appear in scheme code. I think this might be throwing my syntax off. New to scheme so any help would be much appreciated.

```
(define (powFun base exp)
    (if ( = exp 0)                       //base case
     1                                     
       (even? exp                        //if exp is even
          (*
            (powFun base ( / exp 2))
            (powFun base ( / exp 2))
          )

       (*
          (powFun base (- exp 1) )      // else if exp is odd
           base 
       )
     )
  )
```

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`even?` is not similar to `if` - you use it to test whether *one* number is even.
It does not have "branches":

```
> (even? 2)
#t
> (even? 2 "even" "odd")
. . ..\..\Program Files (x86)\Racket\share\pkgs\drracket\drracket\private\rep.rkt:1088:24: even?: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 3
  arguments...:
   2
   "even"
   "odd"
```

You can use it as a test in a conditional:

```
> (if (even? 2) "even" "odd")
"even"
```

If you want to test several conditions, it's convenient to use `cond` instead of `if`:

```
> (define x 3)
> (cond ((= x 1) "one")
         ((even? x) "even")
         (else "odd"))
"odd"
```

But that's not the reason for DrRacket "freezing".

The reason for that is that the division is not an integer division but actually produces an exact fractional result:

```
> (/ 1 2)
1/2
> (/ (/ 1 2) 2)
1/4
> (/ (/ (/ 1 2) 2) 2)
1/8
```

so you will never reach the terminating case.

You should use the `quotient` procedure:

```
> (quotient 3 2)
1
> (quotient 2 2)
1
> (quotient 1 2)
0
```

Making use of the `sqr` procedure and changing your brackets from "C style" to "Scheme style", it might look like this:

```
(define (powFun base exp)
    (if (= exp 0) 
        1                                     
       (if (even? exp)
           (sqr (powFun base (quotient exp 2)))
           (* (powFun base (- exp 1)) base))))
```

Or

```
(define (powFun base exp)
    (cond ((= exp 0) 1)                                    
          ((even? exp) (sqr (powFun base (quotient exp 2))))
          (else (* (powFun base (- exp 1)) base))))

> (powFun 2 3)
8
> (powFun 2 0)
1
> (powFun 2 300)
2037035976334486086268445688409378161051468393665936250636140449354381299763336706183397376
```

Side note: the interaction window is extremely useful for testing small parts of code when you're looking for a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using `even?` as if it was some kind of macro that behaves like `if`. But `even?` is a regular function that takes one argument, so you should have written `(even? exp)` and not `(even? exp evaluate-if-even evaluate-if-not-even)`. That means the return value of `even?` needs its own `if` expression:

```
(if base-case
   1
   (if (even? exp)
       evaluate-if-even
       evaluate-if-not-even))
```

...which means you should be using `cond` instead.

Or, you could define a macro that works the way you thought `even?` worked. Let's call it `if-even`:

```
(define-syntax if-even
    (syntax-rules ()
       ((_ n evaluate-if-even evaluate-if-not-even)
        (if (even? n) evaluate-if-even evaluate-if-not-even))))
```

Then replace `even?` in your original program with `if-even`. Correcting your use of `even?` and then switching to `cond` instead of `if`  is the better option, though.

Answer (score 1):

`if` can only take max 2 clauses, `then` and `else` without keyword. In this situation, you can either use nested `if` or `cond`. Following is an example of `cond`:

```
(cond ((= expr 0) 1)
      ((even? exp) #| do even ... |#)
      (else #| do odd |#))
```